# bar rating - wanting default selection to be no selection

Tags: html

From http://netboy.pl/demo/jquery-bar-rating/examples/  - I'm using the first rating system using 10 bars.  However, I want the default to be no selected option at all (i.e. no bars).  Right now the default selection is option #1 - any thoughts?  I did try adding an empty option but all it did was add another bar to the front (for a total of 11 bars which is not what I want).  I want the 10 bars but none highlighted/selected.  Any thoughts?!?

```
<div class="input select rating-a">
    <select class="example-a" name="content_rating">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure trmb's answer does not do what you asked for.  Did you ever find a proper solution for this with barrating?  I'm looking to do the same thing you were asking.

Comment: no unfortunately never figured this one out - so if you find an answer, please post!

Comment: user1769203 I became frustrated and created my own solution from scratch, so I won't be able to solve anything here :(

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using jquery you can do something like this:

```
$('.example-a').prop("selectedIndex", -1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GAXBf/

Answer (score 2):

URL : http://netboy.pl/demo/jquery-bar-rating/examples/ (This url is not working)

If i am not wrong, you are using jquery bar rating like (http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/examples/).

In this jquery bar rating library, we can set no value selected by default on bar.

```
<script>
$('#rating').barrating('show', {
    theme: 'bars-1to10',
    deselectable: true
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<select id="rating">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    .
    .
    <option value="10">10</option>
</select>
```

Hope, It will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

In case its still relevant. You can add a empty Option.

```
<select id="rating">
   <option value></option>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
   <option value="3">3</option>
   <option value="4">4</option>
   <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

This will give 5 stars with zero filled. Off course this will only work if there is no initial value defined.

Answer (score 2):

```
<select id="example">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone was wondering, in the latest version of the *[jQuery Bar Rating Plugin](https://github.com/antennaio/jquery-bar-rating)* (v1.0.5) you can add the following option to do the trick:

```
<option disabled selected>Select an option</option>
```

So your select box will look something like this:

```
<select>
  <option disabled selected>Select an option</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <!-- etc. -->
</select>
```

Comment: I think it does provide an answer to the question. @user1769203 is/was using the plugin i mentioned, but possibly an older version. In v.1.0.5 my answer definitely works. What should/can I add/say to make my anwer more complete?

Comment: Fair enough.  I suggest a complete example, just to make it clear where the `<option>` goes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @james.garriss. I took your advice and added an example. I'm still learning here ;)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue as the original poster with jQuery Bar Rating (http://antenna.io/demo/jquery-bar-rating/examples/)

When called each option within the select field was transformed to a link wrapped in a div with a class of "br-widget"

I only wanted to display 5 stars for the user to choose from, however the amount of options in the select would determine how many star ratings would show on the screen. The solution I found was to add a "Please Select" as an option and then to hide this using jquery as shown below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(\'#rating\').barrating({
    theme: \'css-stars\' 
    });

  //HIDE THE FIRST STAR OPTIONS
  $(".br-widget a:first-child").css( "display", "none" );


});
```

```html
<select name="rating" id="rating">
  <option value="0">Please Select</option>
  <option value="1">1 Star</option>
  <option value="2">2 Stars</option>
  <option value="3">3 Stars</option>
  <option value="4">4 Stars</option>
  <option value="5">5 Stars</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with this latest 2016 version and i solved it by adding this javascript AFTER the function call and now everything works (hope this help someone):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // remove the selection on the dropdown menu
        $("#rating").val([]);
        // remove all "selected" css to show as "unselected" by default
        $(".br-widget a").removeClass('br-selected');
        // remove default "selected text", if any
        $(".br-current-rating").empty();
});
```

Here is my full code:

```
<script>
    // 5-star rating script
    $(function() {
        $('#rating').barrating({
            theme: 'fontawesome-stars',
            initialRating: null, // initial rating
            showValues: false, // display rating values on the bars?
            showSelectedRating: true, // append a div with a rating to the widget?
            deselectable: true, // allow to deselect ratings
            reverse: false, // reverse the rating?
            readonly: false, // make the rating ready-only?
            fastClicks: true, // remove 300ms click delay on touch devices?
            hoverState: true, // change state on hover?
            silent: false, // supress callbacks when controlling ratings programatically
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function() {
        // remove the selection on the dropdown menu
        $("#rating").val([]);
        // remove all "selectec" css to show as "unselected" by default
        $(".br-widget a").removeClass('br-selected');
        // remove default "selected text", if any
        $(".br-current-rating").empty();
    });
</script>
<style>
    .br-wrapper{
        width: auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .br-widget{
        width: auto;
    }
</style>
```